# install ruby on Rails in mac 10.6.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hi every one I try to install the last version on ruby on rails and I have several problem when run this command

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

The version of my mac is 10.6.8

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.6/i386/ruby-2.0.0-p0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Skipping `brew update` make sure your formulas are up to date.
RVM autolibs is now configured with mode '2' => 'check and stop if missing',
please run `rvm autolibs enable` to let RVM do its job or run and read `rvm autolibs [help]`
or visit https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs for more information.
Missing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, libyaml, readline, libxslt, libksba, openssl, sqlite.
RVM autolibs is now configured with mode '2' => 'check and stop if missing',
please run `rvm autolibs enable` to let RVM do its job or run and read `rvm autolibs [help]`
or visit https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs for more information.
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.
Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation
On OSX 10.6 instead of command line tools install:
    https://github.com/downloads/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/GCC-10.6.pkg
```

download this application and install it, and run again the line to install ruby, but I obtain the same error.

Any idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a known issue with rvm (see: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1671).

The issue was resolved.  Install rvm separately from ruby, then try

`rvm install 2.0.0 --autolibs=4`

to install 2.0.0.

Comment: Hi @Richard Brown thanks for your answer, but when I execute  rmv install 2.0.0 --autolibs=4 the console  don't  find the command-bash: rmv: command not found

Comment: You mean `rvm`, not `rmv`.  Also, make sure `rvm` is installed first: `\curl -#L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=4 --ruby`